# Angular JS: Need to refresh the table headers

Tags: angularjs

I am using standard HTML table to represent the grid and have a button called Reset to reset the default sorting and direction. But I am not able to see the table view reflecting the reset action.

Below is my code snippet

```
<div class="col-md-12 SearchScrollFrame">
  <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
   <thead>
      <tr>          
        <th><a href="" ng-click="toggleHeader('patientLastname')">Last Name<span ng-show="$scope.predicate == 'patientLastname'"><span ng-show="!$scope.reverse">&#9650;</span><span ng-show="$scope.reverse">&#9660;</span></span></a></th>
        <th><a href="" ng-click="toggleHeader('patientFirstname')">First Name<span ng-show="$scope.predicate == 'patientFirstname'"><span ng-show="!$scope.reverse">&#9650;</span><span ng-show="$scope.reverse">&#9660;</span></span></a></th>
        <th><a href="" ng-click="toggleHeader('patientHomePhone')">Telephone<span ng-show="$scope.predicate == 'patientHomePhone'"><span ng-show="!$scope.reverse">&#9650;</span><span ng-show="$scope.reverse">&#9660;</span></span></a></th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="patient in patients  |  orderBy:$scope.predicate:$scope.reverse | filter:$parent.filterResults " >
        <td>{{patient.patientLastname}} {{$scope.predicate}}</td>
        <td>{{patient.patientFirstname}}</td>           
        <td>{{patient.patientHomePhone}}</td>

    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

function myCtrl($scope,$resource,$window) {
       $scope.resetDefault = function() {
              $scope.predicate = 'patientFirstName';
               $scope.reverse = true;

        };

         $scope.toggleHeader = function( header ){
            console.log(header)
             $scope.predicate = header; 
             $scope.reverse=!$scope.reverse; 
         }
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want us to find out why your reset action doesn't work, you'd better post the code of the resat action, and the code using it.

Comment: where your "toggleHeader" function is?

Comment: Also why aren't you using one of the many table libraries out there?

Comment: I updated the original post with the JS code

Comment: I suspect that your filters are not working at all, since you are referencing `$scope` in the HTML, which isn't correct syntax.

Comment: I changed to <tr ng-repeat="patient in patients  |  orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:$parent.filterResults " > and still the problem. Headers are not resetting to firstname including the arrow indicator

Comment: Create a demo that others can fork and modify

Answer (score 0):

You should not include `$scope.` inside the view, for example - this ngShow: `ng-show="$scope.reverse"` should be `ng-show="reverse"`

Also `ng-show="$scope.predicate == 'patientLastname'"` should be replaced with `ng-show="predicate == 'patientLastname'"`

Comment: I did use without $scope. same problem